# Did I trace this recursive code correctly?

Tags: recursion

```
public static void main( String[] args)
{
     down_up( 3 );
}

public static void down_up( int n )
{
    System.out.println(" Level: " + n);

    if( n > 1 )
    down_up(n - 1);
    System.out.println(" LEVEL: " + n);
 }
```

}

I am new to recursion and I just want to make sure that I traced it correctly.

What i got:

```
Level: 3
Level: 2
Level: 1
LEVEL: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost.  You have to remember your call stack:

```
Level: 3
Level: 2
Level: 1
LEVEL: 1
LEVEL: 2
LEVEL: 3
```

Comment: isnt the answer Level: 3, LEVEL: 3, Level: 2, LEVEL: 2, Level: 1, LEVEL: 1?

Comment: No, it's not!  The recursion happens *between* the two lines of output.  You had better read up on call stacks.  In future, please try compiling and running code when you want to test your theories.  I have done that for you here: http://ideone.com/4cpk9s